# Using sed to modify filenames

Tags: sed

Since I don't have `rename`, I would like to use `sed` to modify 192 file names. Specifically, I want to remove the last 5 characters before the file extension; the first character is an `_` and the other 4 are random alphanumeric strings with letters in small or large caps. Example of filenames now:

```
Pyrrhocoridae_Pyrrhocorinae_Pyrrhocorini_Dysdercus_mimus_CMF_0110_S42_L005_R1_001_prinseq_good_30Nd.fastq
Pyrrhocoridae_Pyrrhocorinae_Pyrrhocorini_Dysdercus_mimus_CMF_0110_S42_L005_R2_001_prinseq_good_GyUj.fastq
Pyrrhocoridae_Pyrrhocorinae_Pyrrhocorini_Dysdercus_suturellus_CMF_0305_S71_L005_R1_001_prinseq_good_M99E.fastq
Pyrrhocoridae_Pyrrhocorinae_Pyrrhocorini_Dysdercus_suturellus_CMF_0305_S71_L005_R2_001_prinseq_good_HZrr.fastq
Rhopalidae_Rhopalinae_Harmostini_Harmostes_sp_CMF_0401_S87_L005_R1_001_prinseq_good_96CG.fastq
Rhopalidae_Rhopalinae_Harmostini_Harmostes_sp_CMF_0401_S87_L005_R2_001_prinseq_good_stNk.fastq
```

What I'd like to do with a `sed` script:

```
Pyrrhocoridae_Pyrrhocorinae_Pyrrhocorini_Dysdercus_mimus_CMF_0110_S42_L005_R1_001_prinseq_good.fastq
Pyrrhocoridae_Pyrrhocorinae_Pyrrhocorini_Dysdercus_mimus_CMF_0110_S42_L005_R2_001_prinseq_good.fastq
Pyrrhocoridae_Pyrrhocorinae_Pyrrhocorini_Dysdercus_suturellus_CMF_0305_S71_L005_R1_001_prinseq_good.fastq
Pyrrhocoridae_Pyrrhocorinae_Pyrrhocorini_Dysdercus_suturellus_CMF_0305_S71_L005_R2_001_prinseq_good.fastq
Rhopalidae_Rhopalinae_Harmostini_Harmostes_sp_CMF_0401_S87_L005_R1_001_prinseq_good.fastq
Rhopalidae_Rhopalinae_Harmostini_Harmostes_sp_CMF_0401_S87_L005_R2_001_prinseq_good.fastq
```

I've tried `sed -r 's/good_(.)+.fastq/good.fastq/'` but nothing seems to happen.

Comment: What do you mean you don't have rename?

Comment: my mac osX doesn't have it

Comment: Use `mv` instead, it's short for move

Comment: how can I use `mv` with regexp?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a mac, see here for the available commands:

https://ss64.com/osx/

If you search this page for rename, `mv` comes up as a way to move or rename files.

It's not the same as Windows, it's more like Linux at the command line, which means that there is a lot more you can do with it.

Comment: I'm trying to us `mv`, and I think I might be close to having it work, but so far this doesn't do it: `for f in *.fastq; do mv -- "$f" "${f%_prinseq_good_*}.fastq"; done`. Also tried `for f in *.fastq; do mv -- "$f" "${f%_prinseq_good_????.fastq}.fastq"; done`. Doesn't matter if the `_prinseq_good_` is in the final version of the file names or not.

Comment: Try asking another question and post your script.

Answer (score 0):

Your sed expression

```
sed -r 's/good_(.)+.fastq/good.fastq/'
```

works for me. Either it's an error with your invocation, or a difference of your MacOS sed and my Linux-Gnu-sed.

However, since you don't grab the characters, matching (.)+, you don't need braces:

```
sed -r 's/good_.+.fastq/good.fastq/'
```

should be sufficient, but could be narrowed down to ...

> the first character is an _ and the other 4 are random alphanumeric
>   strings with letters in small or large caps.

I pasted your input into a file "files", and tried

```
sed -r 's/good_(.)+.fastq/good.fastq/' files > files2
```

pasted your desired output to files3, and a diff didn't showed a difference. What do you get? How do you invoke it?

For moving the file, I guess something like

```
 for f in *.fastq
 do
     newname=$(echo "$f" | sed ...) 
     mv "$f" "$newname"
 done
```

Maybe it is an invocation error.

## update:

When I enable --posix style, I need to replace .+ with .* - maybe that's it.

```
sed --posix 's/good_.*.fastq/good.fastq/' files
```

Only worth a hint: The second dot in .*.fastq will match all characters, luckily including the dot itself. Masking it with a backslash would prevent misinterpretation.

Comment: Probably a difference with my MacOS sed

Comment: Does MacOS sed have a --posix mode too? Or is it by default in such?

Comment: From the sed man page on Mac: `The sed utility is expected to be a superset of the IEEE Std 1003.2 (``POSIX.2'') specification.`

Answer (score 0):

This is one you don't actually need sed for, just normal bash:

```
for f in *.fastq; do 
    mv "$f" "${f%_*.fastq}.fastq" 
done
```

Should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems my `mv` command was working, but for some reason my finder was not updating.